# Http through telnet with python and twisted

Tags: python, proxy, twisted, telnet

This is what I want to do:

web-browser --> connect to remote server through telnet(server1) --> to squid-proxy(which requires authentication) through telnet on port 80(server2)

I have written a small python script that uses Twisted (here :

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.web import http
from telnetlib import Telnet
import getpass
from sys import stdout

class datareceiver(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        self.telnet_con.write(data)
        stdout.write( self.telnet_con.read_all() )

    def connectionMade(data):
        stdout.write("\nA connection was made to this server\n")

def main():
    server1 = "10.1.1.1"
    #user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
    password = getpass.getpass()
    tn = Telnet(server1)

    if password:
        tn.read_until("Password: ")
        tn.write(password + "\n")

    #This is server2
    tn.write("telnet 10.1.1.10 80 \n")


    #serverfac = protocol.Factory()
    serverfac = http.HTTPFactory()
    datareceiver.telnet_con = tn
    serverfac.protocol = datareceiver
    reactor.listenTCP(9229,serverfac)

    reactor.run()
    tn.write("exit\n")

    print tn.read_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But then I realized I'm doing it the wrong way, my shell is getting all the replies from squid instead of the browser.
Can someone just outline a correct way of doing this?
Should I use something else instead of twisted?

Comment: Its not really necessary to use python, anything else would also do

Comment: The question is not very easy to understand.  It might help if you try to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have to access a squid-proxy-server(which servers on port 80) through another server(it's a switch actually). I can telnet into the switch and then from there use telnet to connect to the squid-proxy server. In short I want to tunnel my http connection through that switch

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at [twisted.web.server.Site](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.web.server.Site.html) and [twisted.web.resource.Resource](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.web.resource.Resource.html). Also, since you are using Twisted, you'll probably want to use [twisted.protocols.telnet.Telnet](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.protocols.telnet.Telnet.html) for the telnet connection, otherwise your application will not be asynchronous.

[This blog post](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/48953.html) and [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287310/writing-excellent-twisted-web-resources) may also be useful.

Hope this helps!