# Tunnel HTTP via Proxy Using Telnet

Tags: http, networking, telnet, portforwarding

Here is the scenario :
I have to connect to a proxy server(say s1), but it's not accessible directly. As a solution, I can log-in to a remote server(let's call it s2) and then forward my connection to s1.

In connecting to both s1 & s2 I have to use telnet.

```
$>telnet s2
password : 
server s2> telnet s2 80 /stream
Trying s1 80 ...... open
```

What should I do in my application so that I can tunnel all my http connections through this route?

EDIT: I had reversed s1 & s2

Comment: Why not just run another proxy on `s2`? [tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) is compiled and set up in minutes.

Comment: Are the server names in your description reversed from the server names in your example?

Comment: I fixed your title and cleaned up your question. This is not C++, C, or Python related. I also voted to close at Off-topic.

Comment: @Rob : No, they are not reversed.

Comment: @Kerrek : I can't run any proxy on s1. s1 is actually a switch.

Comment: @Code Monkey: I tagged it c++,c & python since I thought I'll have to write a program in one of those languages to achieve my goal.

Comment: Then I am confused by your situation. In your text you say "[s1] is not accessible directly", but in your example you invoke "telnet s1", and it succeeds. So s1 *is* directly accessible? Also, you have said that 's1' is a proxy server, but later you say 's1' is a switch. Can you provide more actual detail and less hypothetical detail?

Comment: @vivek: I understand, but your question does not contain either language and really has nothing to do with them.

Comment: I want to do all this so that I can access StackOverFlow from my University. I can't open this site unless I encrypt my connection :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Http through telnet with python and twisted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354864/http-through-telnet-with-python-and-twisted)

Comment: It is 2019. Telnet was past its best-before-date 20 years ago. Time to join the 21st century.

Comment: For @KerrekSB 's comment, tinyproxy's current website: https://tinyproxy.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Try to tunnel via ssh.... and use localhost:8080 as a proxy

```
ssh -f user@s1 -L 8080:s2:80 -N
```

Comment: @Code Monkey: I don't have a ssh server on any of the servers. So I probably can't use ssh.

Comment: he's asking you how to tunnel through telnet, not through ssh.. minus for that.

Comment: @holms: ssh can tunnel the telnet connection. And the OP is asking for trouble exposing telnet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup [SSH Tunneling with Port Forwarding](http://www.rzg.mpg.de/networkservices/ssh-tunnelling-port-forwarding) to get this to properly work.